# Best way to trim the strings inside my asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a string field name consoleServerPort, and I want to trim all the white spaces inside it before saving it. I use to do so inside my controller class, as follow:-

```
public ActionResult Edit(FirewallJoin fj, FormCollection formValues)
        {
fj.ConsoleServerPort = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(fj.ConsoleServerPort) ? fj. ConsoleServerPort.Trim() : "";
```

But I have to repeat this step on every action method. So I found another way of doing so once at the model level inside an Ivalidatable method as follow:-

```
public partial class TMSFirewall : IValidatableObject
    {
public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
        {

            if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ConsoleServerPort)){
                ConsoleServerPort = ConsoleServerPort.Trim();
            }
```

So is my second approach sound valid? or it is better to use the first approach ?
Thanks

**Edit**
I am using entity Framework and i did the following
i tried the following inside my model class i added the following :-

```
[MetadataType(typeof(TMSSwitchPort_Validation))]
    [Bind(Include = "PortNumber,SwitchID,TechnologyID")]
    public partial class TMSSwitchPort //: IValidatableObject
    {

    }
```

then inside the MetadataType class i added the following :-

```
public class TMSSwitchPort_Validation
    {
        private string consoleServerPort;

        [Required]
        [StringLength(10)]
        [Display(Name="Port Number1111")]
        public String PortNumber
        {
            get { return this.consoleServerPort; }
            set { this.consoleServerPort = value.Trim(); }
        }


    }
```

but the ConsoleServerPort will not be trimmed? can you advice what might be the problem ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Couldn't you do it on the property setter?

```
public class FirewallJoin
{
     private string _consoleServerPort;
     public string ConsoleServerPort
     {
         get
         {
               return _consoleServerPort;
         }
         set
         {
             _consoleServerPort = value.Trim();
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: FirewallJoin is a view model class ,, while TMSFirewall is the model class itself.. so in my way i can guarantee that the ConsoleServerPort will always be trimmed regardless form which view model it is being generated .. so i think my apprach is more valid ?

Comment: Both approaches work so it comes down to a choice of personal preference. I would personally prefer to have the trim handled once on the property and then forget about it. If `TMSFirewall` is the model, then trim the property there instead.

Comment: i already have a metadata validation class as follow  public class TMSFirewall_Validation
    {
        [Display(Name = "Console Server Port")]
        [StringLength(4)]
        public string ConsoleServerPort { get; set; }
       
    }
}.but not sure how i can define the Trim() from there ?

Comment: @johnG Add a private backing field to the property as I've shown and change it from being an auto-property `get;set;` to `get return field; set field = value` etc..